# Updating Environment Variables from .MacOSX/environment.plist

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables

After updating environment variables by modifying the environment.plist file, is there an alternative to logging out and back in again in order to reload the variables and use the new values, much like I would do using `source ~/.bashrc` in bash.

Comment: There's an [alternative approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/3756686#3756686) mentioned on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I would skip the environment.plist and add it directly into my .bashrc file. The you can `source ~/.bashrc` and your variables should be set.

Of course if you are looking for these variables to be available to the UI, then I'm not sure you have any choice.

Comment: Yes, I was wanting them to be available in the UI, unfortunately.